# Marathon OSS: How to inspect elements on JAVA Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, selenium-webdriver, marathontesting

I am exploring Marathon Open Source Java Driver for automation of my Java Swing GUI application.  Added the maven dependency in my pom.xml and downloaded marathon-5.4.0.0 zip file.  Unzipped the marathon zip file in C:/ drive.

Now, I launched my Java Swing based application.  I want to be able to inspect the elements on my Java Swing application through the marathon-5.4.0.0 which I just unzipped.  Added MARATHON_HOME environment variable as well.

Can somebody tell me which application/jar I need to invoke (under marathon-5.4.0.0) in order to inspect the elements on my application?  This will help me use the Marathon Java Driver and build a proper object repository.

My JDK currently points to Java 11, do I need to use JDK 8 only in order to work with it?

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks,
Anukul

Answer (score 0):

Marathon java driver doesn't have inspect object. For that Marathon GUI version needs to be used.

Note: I'm also a contributor of Marathon.